# How to parse a string into a datetime struct in C?

Tags: c, c99

I would like to have a string (char*) parsed into a tm struct in C. Is there any built-in function to do that?

I am referring to ANSI C in C99 Standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While POSIX has [`strptime()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html), I don't believe there is a way to do this in standard C.

Answer (score 11):

There is a function called [strptime()](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strptime.3.asp) available in time.h in UNIX derived systems. It is used similar to `scanf()`.

You could just use a `scanf()` call if you know what format the date is going to be in.

I.E.

```
char *dateString = "2008-12-10";
struct tm * parsedTime; 
int year, month, day; 
// ex: 2009-10-29 
if(sscanf(dateString, "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day) != EOF){ 
  time_t rawTime;
  time(&rawTime);
  parsedTime = localtime(&rawTime);

  // tm_year is years since 1900
  parsedTime->tm_year = year - 1900;
  // tm_months is months since january
  parsedTime->tm_mon = month - 1;
  parsedTime->tm_mday = day;
}
```

Other than that, I'm not aware of any C99 `char *` to `struct tm` functions.