# Date printing and scanning

Tags: c, file, date, printing

I want to read a date from a text file in a single variable/array in this format :

```
Thu Feb 05 16:48:30 2015
```

to print i used :

```
fprintf (savegame,"Played Date : %s ",ctime(&time1));
```

but what to do scan ?

Edit :

Ok . so i probably said something very wrong so i will just reformulate like a task what i get from school... :

I have a text file which contains:

```
 Played Date : Thu Feb 05 16:48:30 2015
 Played Date : Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 1970
```

I want to put them each in a single variable then delete

```
 Played Date :
```

print them and update to the current date.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit : I tried with:

```
fscanf (savegame,"Played Date : %s ",ctime(&time1));
```

but doesn't work....

Comment: Scan the date  Thu Feb 05 16:48:30 2015 in a single variable from savegame.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string into a datetime struct in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722606/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print any date-time format with `strftime()`, so may be you will use format more convenient for scanning. I suppose that `ctime()` is locale-dependent, so on different PC with different settings WeekDay and Month can have different spelling (because of language).

But for your format you can use (my variable names should be changed):

```
      res = fscanf(FP,"%3s %3s %d %d:%d:%d %d",dayStr, monStr, &day, &hour, &min, &sec, &year);
```

and then check format with

```
      if (res == 7) { .... }
```

Comment: `fscanf()` returns the number of successful conversions (an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX, you can parse a date using [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), into a value of type `struct tm`.

You'd first read the entire line of text from the file (`fgets()` is the best choice for that), then pass that to `strptime()`.

If you have static non-date text on the line, you need to skip that first. If it's static, you can just add its length to a pointer to the line, and pass that to `strptime()`. You can also *include* the text in the format string to `strptime()`, and it will be skipped.

Comment: yea but my file has some static text like :  Played Date : Thu Feb 05 16:48:30 2015

Comment: @SzokeLori: If you know the static text, you can write that in the `strptime()` format and it will read past that.