# How to parse values from a C string into a struct timespec

Tags: c, linux

My program will be receiving C string input in the format of `Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT`, e.g.

```
char * date = "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT"
```

How to convert this into a struct timespec so I can compare with the st_atim, st_mtim, and st_ctim `struct timespec`'s returned from the stat() function?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722606/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-struct-in-c) talks about strptime and sscanf, and I also found `strftime`, but all these convert to a `struct time_t` or `struct tm` or integer values.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that returns `timespec`. But it's just seconds and microseconds, so it's easy to create it from anything that returns a unix timestamp, which is seconds.

Comment: If you can get a `time_t` value, it has total seconds. This is what goes in `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` should be set to 0

Comment: Note that this kind of carrying a timestamp is horribly, horribly cumbersome and error prone. For one thing, three-letter timezones **are not unique**, so right off the bat you won't know exactly which time zone the time stamp is **in** when looking at, for example, `CET`. Also, weekday and month names are depending on the locale setting of the machine that did the writing, so out of your control. If you have *any* say on the format, convince them to use something more portable, like e.g. ISO-8601.

Comment: (1) parse out the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second, using your choice of C string-handling techniques. (2) allocate and populate a `struct tm`.  Remember to subtract 1 from the month number, and 1900 from the year.  (3) call `timegm`.  It should return you the `time_t` value you require.  Alternatively, use `strptime`, followed by the same `timegm`.  (Neither `strptime` nor `timegm` are in the official C standard, but most systems should have them.)

Comment: @DevSolar it looks like a date according to RFC 2822 though (like it is used in HTTP headers), which has a clear and unambiguous definition of those things.

Comment: On POSIX-ish systems, use `strptime()` to convert the year-to-seconds information into a `struct tm`, then use `mktime()` to convert that into a `time_t`.  The fractional seconds will need to be handled separately.  There are still some problems to resolve if the input format has the fractional seconds before the end (as in `… 07:28:00.123456789 GMT`) — there isn't a good way to tell `strptime()` to skip an arbitrary number of digits as would be required if the fractional seconds go to nanoseconds.

Comment: @CherryDT: *Assuming* format is another really bad idea. Those week days / months MIGHT be always English, they MIGHT change with locale -- you don't know. Also note that RFC refers to three-letter time zones as "used in an earlier version of this format" *because they are not unique*.

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, of course assumptions are usually a bad thing. But it depends on the actual source of the data. If it is an HTTP header then asking the server to use a different format doesn't make sense as the existing format is well-specified. Of course if it's some random piece of information then they should verify if it's in fact a date according to RFC 2822 or not. More likely than not it is, though, because this format has been around for a long time and has been baked into many libraries. By the way even the timezones are [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-4.3).

Comment: (If you get something that looks like ISO 8601 you can't be sure either what it really is... by the same logic, it could be that they omit the timezone - which is permitted in ISO 8601 and makes it ambiguous again - or it could be not even ISO 8601 at all because someone sends the "week year" instead of regular year, or the month is offset by one, or maybe the year is Chinese or Jewish or whatever. Or maybe it's not a date at all and someone used the format to encode their shoe size. Not likely, sure, but it's also not that likely that this is not RFC 2822.)

Comment: @CherryDT: YYYY-MM-DD was explicitly chosen not only because it's trivially sortable, but because -- strangely enough -- it was not yet used by any existing cultural convention, and thus any YYYY-MM-DD format can safely be assumed to be ISO 8601 (as opposed to basically any other notation being ambiguous). That includes a clear definition of the year. As for your link into RFC 2822 regarding time zones, note that it only "defines" **US** time zones. Without the assertion that the format is, indeed, RFC 2822 compliant, "CET" is more commonly understood as "Central *European* Time"...

Comment: Bottom line, 1) don't assume format, 2) *if you can* (I made that caveat in my original comment already) make the writer use an unambiguous format, 3) ISO 8601 is much less ambiguous than RFC 2822. Let's not defend outdated formats beyond their historic usefulness.

Comment: I agree with all this, actually. (And I also think RFC 2822 is awful from a 2022 point of view because it's more made for humans than it is made for machines.) I just don't think it's practical to apply these things so strictly when working with other software. Sometimes it's part of the job to make good assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the definition of a `timespec`:

```cpp
struct timespec
{
  time_t tv_sec;  // Seconds
  long   tv_nsec; // Nanoseconds
};
```

So, it's nothing other than a `time_t` with an additional number of nanoseconds.

A string like you showed (`Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT`) doesn't even have anything more granular than seconds, so the nanoseconds will hardly matter, and you can just parse it into a `time_t` that goes into `tv_sec` and set `tv_nsec` to zero.

By the way the format you showed is most likely based on the specifications outlined in [RFC 822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc822#section-5) / [RFC 1123](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1123#page-55) / [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14). This should make it a lot easier to search for code that parses it, for example [this](https://www.lemoda.net/c/make-parse-http-dates/index.html). This is also informally known as "HTTP date" due to its use in HTTP headers. In fact, libcurl has a function [`curl_getdate`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_getdate.html) that parses it. You can see its C source code [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/parsedate.c).

Example:

```cpp
#include <curl/curl.h>

timespec ts = {0};
ts.tv_sec = curl_getdate(inputString, NULL);
```

Unless you already use libcurl elsewhere, this could be an unnecessarily large overhead, but you can take it as inspiration or look for other parsing methods that give you a `time_t` as well.